# Split the table into equal chunks based on varchar column Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a huge table with 20 million records and I want to split the table into 10 equal chunks.

The problem is the table only has varchar columns. I am able to use ROWNUM column and split the table into equal chunks but I couldn't seem to get the Start and End value of the varchar column into the query result set. Below is the query.

```
with bkt as (
select ROWNUM, width_bucket(ROWNUM, 1, 100100, 10) as id_bucket from "BOOKER"."test"
)
select id_bucket
   , min(ROWNUM) as bkt_start
   , max(ROWNUM) as bkt_end
   , count(*)
from bkt
group by id_bucket
order by 1;
```

Please advise how can I add the varchar column with this query to give me the start and end varchar values of the column.

Comment: You can use width_bucket on in you select from big table and use multi-table inserts to achieve your task

Comment: width_bucket accepts only integer /date columns due to which I couldn't do that

Comment: I would do what you are already doing - width_bucket(ROWNUM, 1, 100100, 10) in you select from the table.

Comment: yes, with that I could split the table but i'm unable to get the varchar column value for the range in the same query..

Comment: I am assuming you can have something like this -- select YOUR_VARCHAR_COLUMN, width_bucket(ROWNUM, 1, 100100, 10) as id_bucket from your TABLE.. and use it in the multi table insert

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL: How would you split a 100,000 records from a Oracle table into 5 chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335406/sql-how-would-you-split-a-100-000-records-from-a-oracle-table-into-5-chunks)

Comment: Also, rather than having multiple tables, why don't you try partitioning instead? Moreover, 20 million rows isn't much if you have  a primary key and index on appropriate columns.

Comment: There are various different solutions to this sort of problem. Which one might be the most appropriate rather depends on the criteria you want to use to determine the buckets and what you want to do with the result set once you've queried it. Please provide some more details.