# Split Oracle table records into batches and get the maximum an minimum value of the column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, count

I have an oracle table with 3330776 records. I want to split it into batches, so that each batch does not have more than 1 million records. Then I want the minimum and maximum value of a column in each of that batch.
I went through the answer here:
[sql-how-would-you-split-a-100-000-records-from-a-oracle-table-into-5-chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335406/sql-how-would-you-split-a-100-000-records-from-a-oracle-table-into-5-chunks)

But my table has a composite primary Key. And the minimum and maximum value of the column in the batch that I need is amongst one of the composite key columns.

I tried the below query, but I am not getting proper results due to the duplicates in the column PROFILE_ID:

```
select num, min(PROFILE_ID), max(PROFILE_ID)
from
(select t.PROFILE_ID,t.ALIAS,t.ROOT_CONTEXT,t.ROOT_CONTEXT_ID,t.SOURCE, ntile(4) over (order by NULL) as num
from (select t.PROFILE_ID,t.ALIAS,t.ROOT_CONTEXT,t.ROOT_CONTEXT_ID,t.SOURCE
      from DBA_CDD_REVIEW_DS.REVIEW_DATA_STORE t
      where rownum <= 3330776
 ) t )
group by num;
```

Output:

```
1   64      523500
2   64      583101
4   9097    650773
3   4046    613908
```

The following columns constitute the composite primary key for the table:
`PROFILE_ID,ALIAS,ROOT_CONTEXT,ROOT_CONTEXT_ID,SOURCE`

Comment: Please show us the results that you are getting, and those that you would expect. Also, why are you limiting the rows in the subquery (`where rownum <= 100000`)?

Comment: @GMB sorry, I have corrected the details in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Now, what is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: So as you see, the MIN and MAX ranges are overlapping which is not what I want. We would require something like 64-100000, 100001-200000,200201-300000. We do not want it to be like 64-100000, 64-200000,10001-300000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want `ntile()` with an `order by` clause:

```
select num, min(profile_id) min_id, max(profile_id) max_id
from (
    select profile_id, ntile(4) over(order by profile_id) num
    from dba_cdd_review_ds.review_data_store 
) t
group by nt
```

I removed the other columns from the subquery, as well as the filtering on `rownum`, that do not fit well with your problem statement.

That said, I am unsure that `ntile()` is really what you want. You describe a situation where you want to limit the number of rows per bucket to one million. `row_number()` would make more sense, as this would avoid hardcoding the number of buckets as ntile does:

```
select 1 + floor(rn / 1000000) num,  min(profile_id) min_id, max(profile_id) max_id
from (
    select profile_id, row_number() over(order by profile_id) rn
    from dba_cdd_review_ds.review_data_store 
) t
group by 1 + floor(rn / 1000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `NTILE` analytic function you're ordering by NULL, so the database is free to assign whatever rows it wants to each partition. I suggest you do:

```
select num,
       min(PROFILE_ID),
       max(PROFILE_ID)
  from (select t.PROFILE_ID,
               t.ALIAS,
               t.ROOT_CONTEXT,
               t.ROOT_CONTEXT_ID,
               t.SOURCE,
               ntile(4) over (order by PROFILE_ID, ALIAS, ROOT_CONTEXT,
                                       ROOT_CONTEXT_ID, SOURCE) as num
          from DBA_CDD_REVIEW_DS.REVIEW_DATA_STORE t
          where rownum <= 3330776)
  group by num
```

But this requires order by five columns. The following should provide equivalent results:

```
select num,
       min(PROFILE_ID),
       max(PROFILE_ID)
  from (select t.PROFILE_ID
               ntile(4) over (order by PROFILE_ID) as num
          from DBA_CDD_REVIEW_DS.REVIEW_DATA_STORE t
          where rownum <= 3330776)
  group by num
```